# inconsistent behavior with boost::mpl placeholder evaluation

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

In the following code (simplified for demonstration):

```
  namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

  using if1 = mpl::if_<std::is_same<double, mpl::_1>, double, void>;
//using if2 = mpl::if_<std::is_same<double, mpl::_1>, typename std::common_type<double, mpl::_1>::type, void>;

  using apply1 = boost::mpl::apply<if1, double>::type;
//using apply2 = boost::mpl::apply<if2, double>::type;
```

In `std::is_same<double, mpl::_1>`, the placeholder is correctly substituted with `double`, as if the instantiation were explicitly `std::is_same<double, double>` which results in the correct/expected behavior.

However, in `std::common_type<double, mpl::_1>`, the placeholder is **not** substituted, as if the instantiation were explicitly `std::common_type<double, mpl_::arg<1>>`, which causes the following error since there is obviously no "common" type:

```
error: incompatible operand types ('double' and 'mpl_::arg<1>')
```

**The Question:** Why is the `mpl::_1` placeholder correctly transformed/substituted with `double` in `std::is_same`, **but not** in `std::common_type`? And is there a workaround?

Comment: I guess you need `::value` after `std::is_same<...>` and maybe `::type` after `mpl_if_<...>`?

Comment: @leemes: That's not the issue. `mpl::if_` parameter 1 takes an `integral_constant` (which `std::is_same` subclasses). The `if1` works correctly, and `apply1` is `double` as expected. The problem is `if2` with `std::common_type` as explained in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>You're forcing too eager instantiation by accessing the nested `::type` of `std::common_type` before applying the lambda. Replace `typename std::common_type<double, mpl::_1>::type` with `std::common_type<double, mpl::_1>` and you should be all good.</s>

EDIT: Apologies for the bad advice. I didn't see quite what you were doing. Trouble is that `mpl::apply` will turn your placeholder expression into a lambda expression by first running it through `mpl::lambda`. That will cause `std::common_type<double, mpl::_1>` to be wrapped in an `mpl::protect`, which will block it from being evaluated in the first pass, and `mpl::if_` won't evaluate it in the second pass because it treats its second and third parameters as plain types, not placeholder expressions. You can use `mpl::bind` to force `std::common_type` to be evaluated *before* `mpl::if_`. That way, `mpl::if_` sees `if_<some-condition, double, void>`, and all is right again.

```
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/quote.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

template<typename T, typename U> using common_type2 = std::common_type<T,U>;
using if2 = mpl::if_<
                std::is_same<double, mpl::_1>,
                mpl::bind<mpl::quote2<common_type2>, double, mpl::_1>,
                void>;
using apply2 = boost::mpl::apply<if2, double>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<apply2, double>::value, "works");
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks- using `bind` to delay the instantiation of `common_type` (until after `apply` transforms the placeholders) works like a charm.

Comment: Why does mpl wrap `std::common_type<double, mpl::_1>` in `mpl::protect`? Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head. If I discover the reason, I'll edit my response. Or maybe someone else can fill us in.